# Scribus: How can I find images used twice?

Tags: scribus

How can I find images used more than one time in a scribus document?

Is it possible to search a scribus document for images that have been used more than once?

Comment: IMHO this question is better suited for https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com or [su] or do you want to do that search with e.g. python or some other programming language?

Comment: I have the impression that these kinds of questions are not welcome at graphicdesing; an example: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50453/import-spreadsheet-cell-values-into-scribus.

Comment: Hmm, well seems legit, albeit there are a some [scribus](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scribus) questions. What about [SU]?

Comment: A perl script that can do this would be fine.

Comment: in my experience, most of the useful questions and answers i've found in the stackexchange sites have been closed as off topic or as duplicated of less relevant questions / answers. as a scribus contributor and expert, i would say that this question should have been in graphidesign (as would been the same question about an adobe product), but i'm ok with answering it wherever you post it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not really.

But in "Extras > Manage Image" you can have an overview of the images you have used.
It might help you detect duplicates.

You could also write a simple Python script that goes through all images in the document and tells you on which pages you have duplicates...

---

After your feedback in the comments, I've skimmed through https://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Category:Scripts and wrote a simple script that lists the path of each image in your document:

```py
import scribus

for page in range(1, scribus.pageCount() + 1):
    scribus.gotoPage(page)
    for item in scribus.getPageItems():
        if item[1] == 2:
            print(scribus.getImageFile(item[0]))
```

You can easily adapt it to detect duplicated images and do something with them.

You can get further help for the Scribus Python API by going into the help and looking for "For Developers > Scripter API" or in the Scribus Wiki.

And if you produce a script that can be useful for other people do not forget to publish and put a link in here!

Comment: There are a lot of images in the document, so I am searching for a script which can do this.

Answer (score 1):

If we reuse the chunk of code shown by `a.l.e`,
we can naively use a hashmap to ensure if image
is not already found.

Run as Scribus script:

```py
import scribus

db = {}

for page in range(1, scribus.pageCount() + 1):
    scribus.gotoPage(page)
    for item in scribus.getPageItems():
        if item[1] == 2:
            k = scribus.getImageFile(item[0])
            if k in db:
                db[k] += 1
                print(k, db[k])
            else:
                db[k] = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

With this [script](https://github.com/aoloe/scribus-script-repository/blob/master/export-all-text/export_all_text.py) I get usable data in a text file. From there I can use Perl to filter out images used more then once.

---

How I executed the script:

Open the sla-file with Scribus.

Select in the Scribus menu bar `Scripter -> Show Console` which opens a new window: Script Console

In the Script Console menu bar:

`File -> Open` and select the python script; then

`Script -> Run`

Comment: yes, it's a good start. the script i've posted is a (probably cleaner and) simpler version of what you have found in there. i've now also pushed the ad hoc script to the repository where i publish smaller snippets: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aoloe/scribus-script-collection/master/list-all-images/list-all-images.py